# Problem with dataframe created from an old df

Tags: dataframe, nan, int64

I try to create a new dataframe with columns from an existing one but it does not work as expected.    The first df is created by reading a csv

for example

```
a  b  c
1  1  0
0  1  1
0  0  0
1  0  0

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['a'])

a    
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

How can i fix this? In the first dataframe dtype of 'a' is `int64`.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution, your syntax is slightly wrong:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a'])
df2['a'] = df['a']
df2


    a
0   1
1   4
2   7
```

Comment: I tried that too. In this error i take an key error. Also i want to use several columns from the old df.

Comment: As @Baume has noted in his answer, you can select multiple columns with
df2[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']].

Comment: If you still get an error can you add the code of how you create the dataframe 'df'?

Comment: I just read a csv file. data = pd.read_csv('autism_screening.csv').   Then i code df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b', ....]) and i take NaN in some columns. I also tried  df2[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']] but i have an error.

Comment: So if you run my code above or the one from @think-maths it throws an error as well or only when you use it on your own dataframe?

Comment: I still have error. I can not understand why. Even when there is no error the values are converted in NaN

Answer (score 1):

@pookpash solutions also works with multiple columns like this;

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a', 'b'])
df2[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a couple of options. If you know from context which variables you want to slice out, you can just return a view of only those columns by passing a list into the `__getitem__ syntax`

```
df2 = df[['a', 'b']]

>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
>>> df2 = df[['a']]
>>> df2
   a
0  1
1  4
2  7
```

Alternatively, if it matters to index them numerically and not by their name (say your code should automatically do this without knowing the names of the first two columns) then you can do this instead

```
df2 = df.iloc[:, 0:2]
```

Also if you just want to make a copy of DataFrame use:

```
df2 = df.copy()
```

Use whatever fits your problem

Comment: I use exactly the first way you proposed. Again i have an error ```KeyError: ['a'] not in index.

Comment: What is wrong with this syntax? It works but the 'a' column turns into NaN.df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['a'])

Comment: can you edit your in question how you have created `df` DataFrame. I have updated my answer to show that I am getting the output as you mentioned

Comment: what I read from the below comment of yours you are reading a `csv file` so whenever you do `pd.read_csv` it creates a DataFrame so the variable `data` of yours is itself a DataFrame you need not do ` pd.DataFrame(data)` again

Comment: I finally fixed it. Thank you all!

Comment: great, as per SO practices accept the answer whichever helped you in your question